# Is there a function I can create to push the entire alphabet to an array?

Tags: ruby

I need to create an array, and set each of its index to an individual letter of the alphabet. I could do it in Javascript using CharCodes, but I have not found anything for Ruby that does something similar. I don't feel like typing `["a", "b"..."z"]`.

Comment: This will do it `[*'a'..'z']`.

Comment: ...which is the same as `('a'..'z').to_a`. There's really nothing more to be said!

Comment: @SagarPandya Thanks!

Comment: @CarySwoveland: You _could_ say `[*?a..?z]`... :P

Comment: @Amadan, or `"the quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox".delete(' ').each_char.uniq.sort`. That's the version of the expression my dog prefers.

Comment: @CarySwoveland hahahaha, I did not get until I run it on the irb, hilarious!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use `..` to create a [Range](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Range.html).

```
letters = ('a'..'z')
```

These are [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerable.html) so you can iterate over the range without needing to turn it into an Array. For large ranges this can save memory.

```
("a".."z").each { |letter| p letter }
```